# How to style only direct children?

Tags: css

I'm modifying an old-ish site that was styled with a combination of tables & css.  Before anyone says anything, switching to pure CSS isn't an option.

I have this structure:

```
table.grid
  tr
    td
      table
        tr
          td
```

And in the CSS, there is `.grid td` with a padding.

It seems like the `.grid td` style is being applied to the inner td (the one furthest down the chain).  Is there a way to tell `.grid td` to style *only* `td` tags within that specific table?

(I'm far from a CSS master, so if I'm barking up the wrong tree here, please let me know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` character is used to indicate only direct descendants.

```
.grid > tr > td { /* style me! */ }
```

To address @bazmegakapa's concern about a potential `tbody`, I'd change it up to be:

```
.grid > tr > td, .grid > tbody > tr > td { /* no worries */ }
```

Comment: That's perfect!  I'll accept you as the answer since you're the first!

Comment: @MattGrande Some browsers insert a `tbody` element so it might not work in all of them.

Answer (score 4):

`table.grid > tr > td, table.grid > tbody > tr > td` should do what you want -  `a > b` specifies that for the selector to apply, `b` must be a direct descendant of `a`. You need the second form because many browsers will generate a tbody.

This won't work: `.grid tr > td`, because the inner table is a descendant of `.grid`.

Comment: Except that some browsers will insert a `tbody` element to correct the invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
table.grid > tr > td
```

might hav probs if you come across tables with thead, tbody, tfoot

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`>` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). Using `table.grid > tr > td` would only apply to `td` elements directly below `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You can be more specific by selecting only the `td`s inside the `tr` of `table.grid`

```
.grid > tr > td
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it like this :

```
 table.grid > tr > td
```

But I'm not sure it works.